# \Longrightarrow does not work properly in mathastext.sty

Tags: mathastext

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[defaultmathsizes,italic]{mathastext}%
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
x \in L &\Longrightarrow \big|\vec{a}_x \cdot \mathcal{U} \vec{a}_x\big|^2 \geq 1 - \epsilon(n),\\
x \notin L &\Longrightarrow \big|\vec{a}_x \cdot \mathcal{U} \vec{a}_x\big|^2 \leq \epsilon(n).
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

This works without error, but the output of `\Longrightarrow` looks like kerning of `=` sign and `\leftarrow`, and it looks very odd:

[image]

I'm using `MikTeX 2.9` `PDFLaTeX` on Windows7 system, and I'm in need to use this same setup with the package `mathastext`, please suggest...

Comment: You should load `mathastext` after `mathtools`. But why don't you use the `newtx` fonts?

Comment: Much thanks, its working fine, It's one of a old document, and they did like that, if I change to `txfonts` then the line ending are affected. Also, if I use the options `noequal,nominus, i.e., `\RequirePackage[defaultmathsizes,italic,noequal,nominus]{mathastext}` works fine, is it safe to procedd?